# how to decrypt string using private key

Tags: php, openssl

how to decrypt an encrypted string using private key

I tried this code but returned string was empty

what is the problem

I get more than one error

```
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt


if (!$cert_store = file_get_contents(storage_path('certificates/Naq.pfx')))
    {
      return "Error: Unable to read the cert file\n";
    }
    if (openssl_pkcs12_read($cert_store, $cert_info, "P@ssw0rd")) 
    {
       $certInfo   = $cert_info['cert'];
       $privateKey = $cert_info['pkey']; // private key
       $extracerts = $cert_info['extracerts'][0]; 
         
       $encrypted = base64_decode($request_decryption_key);
       openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $privateKey);
       return $decrypted;
    } 
    else {
       return "Error: Unable to read the cert store.\n";
    }
```

Comment: Without example input, keys, and expected output we cannot offer any useful information as we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are talking about a **hybrid encryption** and that usually means that you work in 3 steps: 1) generate a random AES key, 2) encrypt the data/message with this AES key, 3) encrypt the AES key with the **public key** of the recipient. The decryption runs the other way round: 1) decrypt the (encrypted) AES key with the **private key** of the recipient, 2) decrypt the (encrypted) data with the (now decrypted) AES key. Break the code into these steps and debug the input and output - you will find the code line where the data looks like different. Please edit your question -> minimal example.

Comment: kindly see the updated post